# converting string to int crashing the program

Tags: python

I have this code running in a number guessing game I have written, it runs perfectly fine if the player follows the instructions, but as we all know users never do. If the user enters just a space or any string thats not the word hint then it crashes saying invalid literal for int() with base 10: when trying to convert the value of guess to an integer. Is there any way around this or am I just going to have to live with the crashes?

```
while repeat==1:
    repeat=0
    level1number=str(level1number)
    guess=input("What is your guess? ")
    guess=guess.lower()
    if guess==level1number:
        print("Well done, You have guessed my number!")
    elif guess=="hint":
        print("Hints are not available until level 3")
        repeat=1
    elif guess!=level1number:
        print("Sorry that is not my number, you have lost a life. :(")
        lives=lives-1
        repeat=1
        if lives<=0:
            print("You have lost all your lives, so this means I win")
            print("The program will now end")
            exit()
            input("")
        level1number=int(level1number)
        guess=int(guess)
        if guess<level1number:
            print("The target number is higher")
        else:
            print("The target number is lower")
```

Comment: Catch the exception and keep asking a valid value.

Comment: There are many ways around this. The easiest is probably using a `while` loop and `try` `except` block to keep asking the user for input if it can't be converted to `int`.

Comment: it runs the not equal to section of the loop if its not the target number or the word hint, causing the crash

Comment: You shouldn't cast `level1number` to `str` and `guess` should be an integer as soon as possible.

Comment: What is your `level1number`? Please show us the whole code

Comment: guess the error should be coming from core "guess=int(guess)"

Comment: sorry, level1number=random.randint(1,5)

Comment: and i know the error is from guess=int(guess) i just dont know how i can get around it

Comment: @PineappleLord: Have a look at my answer. Using `try` block is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while repeat==1:
    repeat=0
    level1number=str(level1number)
    guess=input("What is your guess? ")
    guess=guess.lower()
    if guess==level1number:
        print("Well done, You have guessed my number!")
    elif guess=="hint":
        print("Hints are not available until level 3")
        repeat=1
    elif guess!=level1number:
        print("Sorry that is not my number, you have lost a life. :(")
        lives=lives-1
        repeat=1
        if lives<=0:
            print("You have lost all your lives, so this means I win")
            print("The program will now end")
            exit()
            input("")
        level1number=int(level1number)
        try:
            guess=int(guess)
            if guess<level1number:
                print("The target number is higher")
            else:
                print("The target number is lower")
        except:
            print("Try again. Not a number")
```

Using `try/except` block would solve your problem. Have a look

**Edit:** In the question. you mentioned that you get an error when something other than a number is entered. Actually, it is an `exception` that is thrown when your code tries to convert your input string to a number when it is not possible(`guess = int(guess)`) due to the input not being a number, just like a `space`. So, what my code does, is that it catches the exception, and does not allow the program to terminate with the exception.

Just try it once. I know you are beginner but it is better to learn about `exception handling` as soon as possible, before you write more and more complex codes and applications.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks, im not a professional and i have never heard of try/except

Comment: i have accepted the answer, just my reputation isnt high enough for it to be visible

Answer (score 4):

Use something as

```
if guess.isdigit() ...
```

(method `isdigit()` returns true if and only if all characters of a given string are digits, i.e. 0 to 9).

Comment: This is the best answer (so far); *while* it returns False then make it keep asking the user for his input again.

Comment: @MarianD Do you know of a signed version of this?  For instance '-1'.isdigit() will return false but can evaluate to a number.  '-1'.isnumeric() will also return false